# How to test Spring Webmvc webservice rest

Tags: java, spring, rest, tomcat

I have a little question about Spring Webmvc. I'm trying to make a web application with a restful webservice but I don't know if it is correctly working.

I have a maven-webapp project with this class :

```
...
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
...

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service")
public class PersoWsRest {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/lister", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Perso> listerPersos() {
        System.out.println("PASSAGE DS LE WEB SERVICE\n");

        List<Perso> res = new ArrayList<Perso>();

        res.add(new Perso("Test", "Un"));
        res.add(new Perso("Test", "Deux"));
        res.add(new Perso("Test", "Trois"));

        return res;
    }

}
```

and, when I launch my tomcat server (with no error), I can't manage to try my web service.

I think, it is two issues :

- I don't use the correct URL but I'm trying lot of URL...so...
- I don't make the correct configuration of Spring WebMvc.

Do you have an idea ? Thanks.

Comment: Please specify 3 things : your web application context path (web application path), the URL mapping for your dispatcher servlet and the URL you are using to access this service.

Comment: You need to add more details before anyone can help you

Comment: What port is your local tomcat running, 8080? What is the context path? The URL should be something like localhost:8080/webappcontext/server/lister but without more detail it is difficult to help.

Comment: If I were you I would try changing the logging level for the spring rest config. You should be able to get it to print out to the console the different endpoints. Either you will find a different URL to the one you expect or something is failing to load.

Comment: I found the errors :) thanks.

I didn't have configuration with web.xml

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for sample code to start with here it is.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(PersoWsRest.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class PersoWsRestTest{

 @Autowired
 MockMvc mockMvc;

 @Test
public void testListerPersos(){
    MvcResult mvcResult = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/service/lister")
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();
//..... Further validation
      }    
    }
```